# How do you decode a JSON field using the PG gem?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

I am using [PG](https://rubygems.org/gems/pg).  I have a table with a column of type JSON.  Querying the table is easy, but I am not sure how to decode the JSON field:

```
$pg.exec('SELECT id, meta FROM users') do |result|
  result.each do |row|
    puts row['meta']
    Oj.load(row['meta'])
  end
end
```

The `row['meta']` field doesn't contain valid JSON, so `Oj.load` raised an error.  What is the best way to decode JSON fields via the PG gem?

Comment: If the column is type JSON, how is it possible it doesn't contain a valid JSON? What's inside? What error are you receiving?

Comment: When asking about "how to decode json", you need to also show the content of the JSON field resulting from the query, especially when you say it doesn't contain valid JSON. JSON is a string, even inside the database so GIGO will apply. Please read "[mcve]". Also, rather than use PG directly, I'd strongly recommend using [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) as it's less likely to paint you into a corner when you write SQL.

Comment: Also, storing JSON inside the database isn't a good idea if you're going to need to search/alter the fields inside the JSON. Instead, store the individual field's data as regular DB fields so you can take advantage of indexing and all the other goodness the DBM brings with it. Your speed and flexibility will be much better that way.

Comment: If he's writing a low-level gem specific to Postgres like `que` then Sequel might not be a dependency he wants to pull in. He might also have perfectly valid reasons to use JSON instead of a normalized schema.

Comment: He's not writing a gem, he's using Pg. While it's possible there's well-informed decisions behind using Pg, odds are good Sequel will be a better base as it removes the hassles of using raw-SQL and having to convert PGSQL's internal data types into Ruby data-types. We use JSON and Pg inside Sequel all day long; It's easy to use and extremely convenient.

Comment: I'm not going to use sequel, my question doesn't deal with sequel, it's dealing with pg.  The JSON string is contained within braces "{}", different than what is in the sql column according to psql.  I am not sure which layer includes these braces, is it gem pg or PostgreSQL.  In psql, the JSON column is looks like: 

`{"created_at":"2016-01-05T18:06:34.809Z"}`

in a ruby script when called with pg.exec, the result looks like:

`"{{\"created_at\":\"2016-01-05T18:06:34.809Z\"}}"`

Comment: Aha. The field is of type json[] not json. So the result needs to be decoded as a Postgres array of json.

Answer (score 3):

The column is of type `json[]`, and the way to decode it is:

```
decoder = PG::TextDecoder::Array.new
$pg.exec('SELECT id, meta FROM users') do |result|
  result.each do |row|
    meta = decoder.decode(row['meta'])
    meta.each do |meta_entry|
      puts Oj.load(meta_entry)
    end
  end
end
```

This required the pg gem version 18.*